# Why use window.onload

Tags: javascript

I have tried finding an answer to this on my own, but only found instructions on how to use onload events. I seem to be missing the point.

I've been taught that if I want something to happen when the page loads, I should use window.onload like this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = dosomething();

    function dosomething()
    {
        window.alert('hello');
    }
</script>
```

But now that I am thinking on my own I wonder what the point of doing that is. Because this also produces the same result:

```
<script>
    dosomething();

    function dosomething()
    {
        window.alert('hello');
    }
</script>
```

Anything I put at the top inside `<script>` is going to execute anyway... so what's the point of window.onload?

Comment: There's a difference between "immediately execute this when the parser encounters it" and "run this when the entire page has been loaded" (which is what `onload` does). Sometimes that difference doesn't matter, but sometimes it does - if you need to do things after images have been loaded, for example.

Comment: appreciated, thank you!

Comment: To use an analogy, in some situations it's important to know that you have your pants on before you go walking around. Yet, in other situations it might not be as important.  Your second snippet is walking without pants.

Comment: I liked that, @Roberto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're directly running your code with `dosomething();`, you're delaying your browser's rendering for the time it takes your JavaScript code to run.

You can try to insert your code to the `<head>` of your html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
dosomething();

function dosomething()
{
    window.alert('hello');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Does not render before the alert is dismissed!
</body>
</html>
```

You'll see that the page stays blank until you dismiss the alert. So every second the browser takes to run your JavaScript code is a second that your users have to wait for the site to be rendered.

Now if you change the code to be run on body's `onload`, the page gets rendered *before* the alert is shown:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function dosomething()
{
    window.alert('hello');
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="dosomething()">
This page gets rendered before the alert!
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you @jehna1. that puts it in perfect perspective for me.

Answer (score 2):

Consider these two blocks of code:

```
<head>
     <script>
          alert(document.getElementById('foo').value);
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="foo" value="hello">
</body>
```

---

```
<head>
     <script>
          window.onload = function() {
              alert(document.getElementById('foo').value);
          }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="foo" value="hello">
</body>
```

In the first example, we'll get an error because the element you are referencing isn't found when the script runs - and so you are trying to get `value` of `null`.

In the second example, `document.getElementById()` will find the element with the id foo, because `window.onload` will get fired only when the complete DOM has been loaded and so the element is available.

Answer (score 1):

`window.onload` will fire once the DOM has finished loading. In your example, the DOM is not required. However, the following code will fail if the DOM has not yet loaded:

```
function doSomething() {
  alert(document.getElementById('test').innerText);
}

// Throws: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
```

Assuming your page contains an element with id `test`, it will alert its text.

Answer (score 1):

waiting for the onload event assures you that all of your scripts and resources are loaded

Assume you are using jquery in your page and you invoked a function that uses it directly without onload , you can't guarantee that the jquery file has been loaded, which will lead to errors and possibly ruining your whole logic

Answer (score 1):

The onload event is handy to make sure the page is fully loaded before you run a script. For your example above it doesn't make sense, but if your page is still loading an item on the bottom and you try to call it then nothing will run.

I recommend using jQuery and using the ready function. This way you will ensure your page is completely loaded.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // This will only run after the whole page is loaded.
});
```

If you don't want to load query, just put your javascript at the bottom of the page. It's best practice, and ensures the DOM is loaded in full.

For more info on the jquery ready function go here: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Not sure if I will ever use jquery (I thought improvements to JS were replacing the need for jquery?), but thank you :)

Comment: You are right, you can get aways without using jQuery, but it's still going strong. Just look at Twitter Bootstrap and Foundation by Zurb. They both include jQuery by default. 

So are there better or faster libraries? Likely. 
Is jQuery slightly slower than native JavaScript? Sure. 
Does it make development easier? Absolutely. 

I think that jQuery will be around for a good long while. Thought I am sure that some other library will replace it in the future.