# Invoking a JS function from outside of html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm uber new to js. I looked around at couple of other posts and it seems like this should be able to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./web3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./request_balance_script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./get_hash.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        getHash()
    </script>
<body>
    <h1>Transaction Hash Fetch.</h1>
    <p>Here is the hash for "Transfer(address,address,uint256)"</p>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what `./get_hash.js` looks like.

```
function getHash() {
    console.log("Preparing to hash transaction.");
    var hash = web3.utils.keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)");
    console.log("Hashed transaction ="+hash);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = hash;
}
```

Why would `getHash()` be undefined?

Comment: `getHash()` is being called before `get_hash.js` has loaded. look at only making the call when document is ready - look at (DOMContentLoaded)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event] and move the call to getHash inside that handler - otherwise you won't have access to dom elements either

Comment: You might be calling the function before your script is fully loaded.  Wrap it with `window.onload`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951299/why-use-window-onload

Comment: @PM77-1 that's what happened. Thank you!

Comment: @SamuelG That's what happened, thank you!

Comment: @SamuelG How can I wrap a `script` section in a `window.onload`? `request_balance_script.js` sets up the web3 connection so I want to wait until it's done before proceeding with the script.

Comment: See demo below - simply add all your scripts like you were, but then add `DOMContentLoaded` before body tag closes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments:

1. your `getHash` function is being called before the contents of the `get_hash.js` has loaded
2. you are also accessing dom elements before they have been loaded

Wait until the script and dom have loaded before you begin processing. Look at [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event.

Snippet example to outline:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script language="javascript">
  function getHash() {
    console.log("Preparing to hash transaction.");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 'mocked data';
  }
</script>

<body>
  <h1>Transaction Hash Fetch.</h1>
  <p>Here is the hash for "Transfer(address,address,uint256)"</p>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
      getHash();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```